# Node.js Twitter Client

Tags: node.js, twitter

Is there a twitter client for node.js (not the streaming API, the regular API)?

I already know about [twitter-node](https://github.com/rodrigopinto/twitter-node) but I'm looking for a more generic client that allows use of the [Twitter REST API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc#rest-api).

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,

Johnathan

Comment: @Raynos you also need to do OAuth..? A library would be useful for that :P..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check out my node module, it is probably what you're looking for. Has full twitter API support (REST & Streaming API): https://github.com/ttezel/twit

Comment: hi Ivreiny, 
when you console.log() you are adding the string 'List of following ids:\n' to the reply object, which results in a string output to your terminal. If you want to actually be able to see the reply object, just console.log(reply). Another thing is that in your params object, `sreen_name` should be `screen_name`. Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: It is solved. I should have used "reply.ids.toString" in the console.log() instead of "reply". Thanks!

Comment: awesome. If anything else comes up, I'd love to help. it's a bit easier if you message me through github, but I'll try to check here too :)

Comment: Personally the one that has given me the least hassle :)

Comment: hi, can someone tell how I can use update_with_media api using twit?I am having trouble in sending the media parameter.Any help would be great.Thanks.In case you want to answer it as a sepearate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18996140/how-to-perform-a-update-with-media-post-request-using-twit

Comment: @Aravind -- This modules does not support media upload yet.  See https://github.com/ttezel/twit/issues/43

Answer (score 14):

## 2014 Update

A lot has changed since this question was asked over 3 years ago, but this question is still highly ranked on search engines so it's time to add some updates.

There are many different Node modules to use with the Twitter API and it is not easy to choose the right one for someone who doesn't know all of them. Below is a short description of all of the currently popular modules, together with their authors, latest version, how many stars on GitHub do they have (which is a good indication of their popularity among GitHub users), how many commits, how many contributors, where were they recommended etc. There are also some useful usage stats on [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/).

Since it is about Twitter, I will link to the Twitter profiles of people that I reference. The data is up to date as of 2014-07-29 and isn't meant to be always up to date but rather to show a snapshot in time for various comparisons.

On the official [**dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries**](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries) there are only two Node modules:

### [TwitterJSClient](https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient) by [@BoyCook](https://twitter.com/BoyCook)

- (Version 0.0.1, 87★, 2 contributors, 19 commits - last on May 06, 2014) ([not available on npm?](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=TwitterJSClient))

### [user-stream](https://github.com/aivis/user-stream) by [@AivisSilins](https://twitter.com/AivisSilins)

- (Version 0.0.7, 57★, 1 contributor, 26 commits - last on Mar 28, 2014) ([npm stats](https://www.npmjs.org/package/user-stream))

The articles:

- [Node.js modules you should know about: ntwitter](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/nodejs-modules-ntwitter/) posted on December 09, 2011 by [@pkrumins](https://twitter.com/pkrumins)
- [Node.js + Twitter Streaming API + Socket.io = Twitter Cashtag Heatmap](http://dillonbuchanan.com/programming/node-js-twitter-streaming-api-socket-io-twitter-cashtag-heatmap/) posted on April 18, 2013 by [@thedillonb](https://twitter.com/thedillonb)

both recommend:

### [ntwitter](https://github.com/AvianFlu/ntwitter) by [AvianFlu](https://github.com/AvianFlu) (no Twitter?) et al.

- (Version 0.5.0, 765★, 31 contributors, 245 commits - last on Sep 14, 2012) ([npm stats](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ntwitter))

The article [A Twitter bot in 20 minutes with Node.js](http://www.apcoder.com/2013/10/03/twitter-bot-20-minutes-node-js/) posted on October 3rd, 2013 by [@ebertx](https://twitter.com/ebertx]) recommends:

### [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) by [@tolga_tezel](https://twitter.com/tolga_tezel)

- (Version 1.1.18, 806★, 11 contributors, 296 commits - last on Jul 21, 2014) ([npm stats](https://www.npmjs.org/package/twit))

[The most popular Twitter modules](https://nodejsmodules.org/tags/twitter) according to [nodejsmodules.org](https://nodejsmodules.org/) by [@corruptmem](https://twitter.com/corruptmem) are:

(listing only the relevant ones from the list - eg. skipping blueimp-bootstrap-image-gallery etc.)

### [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) by [@briannoguchi](https://twitter.com/briannoguchi)

- (Version 0.4.6, 2822★, 47 contributors, 760 commits - last on Apr 30, 2014) ([npm stats](https://www.npmjs.org/package/everyauth))
- **(Note: it's a general-purpose authentication module)**

### [ntwitter](https://github.com/AvianFlu/ntwitter) by [AvianFlu](https://github.com/AvianFlu) (no Twitter?) et al.

- (see above)

### [twitter-node](https://github.com/technoweenie/twitter-node) by [@technoweenie](https://twitter.com/technoweenie)

- (Version 0.1.1, 436★, 10 contributors, 65 commits - last on Apr 15, 2012) ([npm stats](https://www.npmjs.org/package/twitter-node))
- **(Note: Discontinued and recommends ntwitter)**

### [node-twitter](https://github.com/jdub/node-twitter) by [@jdub](https://twitter.com/jdub)

- (forked from twitter-node - see above)
- (on npm called just "twitter")
- (Version 0.1.18, 313★, 9 contributors, 162 commits - last on Mar 10, 2012) ([npm stats](https://www.npmjs.org/package/twitter))

### [twitterlib](https://github.com/remy/twitterlib) by [@rem](https://twitter.com/rem)

- (Version 1.1.4, 289★, 3 contributors, 89 commits - last on Jun 21, 2013) ([npm stats](https://www.npmjs.org/package/twitterlib))

### [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit) by [@tolga_tezel](https://twitter.com/tolga_tezel)

- (see above)

This is what I have found to be a list of most popular Node modules to use the Twitter API. Please note that the most popular doesn't necessarily mean the best. All of them have different APIs, popularity, feature sets, authors, documentation, users. It's impossible to recommend only one module but this list should be a good starting point to find the one that is best suited for a particular set of needs.

Please comment if there are any mistakes or missing modules or other info that should be added here.

Answer (score 3):

Search via http://search.npmjs.org:

- https://github.com/jdub/node-twitter

  I believe it also supports REST-API and is more up2date(more recent commits).

Answer (score 3):

There is [ntwitter](https://github.com/AvianFlu/ntwitter), which was updated within the last couple of months.   For me, the hardest part about getting a script up and running to post twitter messages was navigating the auth configuration at dev.twitter.com for the first time.     ntwitter handled the rest!

Comment: From the github: "ntwitter is an improved version of jdub's node-twitter, which in turn was inspired by, and uses some code from, technoweenie's twitter-node."