# http authorization header in html

Tags: html, oauth, header, authorization

I need help in setting the authorization header in html file. So I used OAuth tool on dev.twitter.com and got this header content:

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="BKsXdR3SO4hSZyFT2JevHQ", oauth_nonce="718a5099a51230e737474c7e76d21581", oauth_signature="rQ5DJWi8qMmdR76rwIOwJYUhuvc%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1341342796", oauth_token="69848552-B6geQZCA8ttirQIMKrIk47SOE541V7d5ZcYwEBUqQ", oauth_version="1.0"
```

Now I don't know what to do. I tried this:

```
<meta name="Authorization" content="OAuth" 
    oauth_consumer_key="BKsXdR3SO4hSZyFT2JevHQ", 
    oauth_nonce="b98cf39b3f8dba6286cbd1b741eb7504", 
    oauth_signature="Vgmudlrkv1dzFel9zpFztXfR6gI%3D", 
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
    oauth_timestamp="1341339879", 
    oauth_token="69848552-B6geQZCA8ttirQIMKrIk47SOE541V7d5ZcYwEBUqQ", 
    oauth_version="1.0">
```

But it doesn't work! I am sure doing something wrong.

Help, please!

Aram.

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do. Do you e.g. want people to login to your site using their Twitter Account?

Comment: No, I just want to authorize myself as owner to have an access to all data. I can't do it without simple Authorization header. But I don't know how to make it. Should I do it in my html-file or in any other? And what the hell this header is?

Comment: So what data do you want from Twitter and what do you want to do with it? In which language are you developing your backend?

Comment: I want json data with tweets' texts and locations. But it's okay, I use JS. Actually, I don't use anything except HTTP and JS. Because I'm junior developer and I have no experince. So, I thought that HTTP-header is header in HTML-file between "<meta>"-tags. I was wrong, and I can't find any useful information in Google. So I've tried to register here and to ask question.

Comment: You are having static HTML pages and some JS on it or a JS backend (like node.js)? For latter you should look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377844/node-js-twitter-client

Answer (score 4):

There's an essential difference of headers. OAuth requires an "Authorization" on HTTP header, not in HTML header.

```
POST /1/statuses/update.json?include_entities=true HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Connection: close
User-Agent: OAuth gem v0.4.4
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: 
        OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog", 
              oauth_nonce="kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg", 
              oauth_signature="tnnArxj06cWHq44gCs1OSKk%2FjLY%3D", 
              oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
              oauth_timestamp="1318622958", 
              oauth_token="370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb", 
              oauth_version="1.0"
Content-Length: 76
Host: api.twitter.com
```

You can set this headers on a request through server-side scripting (with PHP, Python, ...)

Comment: So, how should I require future PHP-file with Post request in my html-file?

Comment: I think that you are misunderstanding the concept of the authentication... You can see a example of OAuth rigth in this page http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/twitter-app-oauth-php/

Comment: I am sorry but your link was not useful. I could not find any information about making headers or requests or anything related to my question. But, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do HTTP requests (specifically [XMLHttpRequests](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)) from Javascript using AJAX calls (e.g. with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)). Check the example for the [Perfect jQuery AJAX Request](http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/the-perfect-jquery-ajax-request/). Then you also can also set your [request header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3258685/1467115).