# How to perform an update with media POST request using twit?

Tags: json, node.js, api, twitter

I am using [twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit). Update status(without media) works fine, but [update with media](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media) is not working.
This is my code (used with express):

```
//client side

<form id="tweeter" action='/image' method='POST' >
  <input type="text" name="tw" id="tw" />
  <input type='file' name='img' id='img' /> 
  <input type="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>


 //server side

app.post('/image',function(req,res){
  var f= "./" +req.body.img;
  console.log(req.body.img);
  T.post('statuses/update_with_media', 
    { status: req.body.tw, media: f }, 
    function(err, reply) {
      console.log('ERROR:' +err);
      console.log('REPLY:' +reply);
    }
  );
});
```

The error I am getting is **'Missing or invalid url parameter'**.
How should I send the image file via `media[]`?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your form has a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and instead of `req.body.img` try using `req.files.img`

Check what kind of input T.post wants from the media parameter, you could try base64

example client code:

```
<form id="tweeter" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='/image' method='POST' >
   <input type="text" name="tw" id="tw" />
   <input type='file' name='img' id='img' /> 
   <input type="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```

example server code:

```
app.post('/image',function(req,res){
    var f = fs.readFileSync(req.files.img.path,'base64');
    T.post('statuses/update_with_media', {status: req.body.tw, media:f}, function(err, reply) {
        console.log('ERROR:'+err);
        console.log('REPLY:'+reply);
    });
});
```

Comment: I included the fs library, and tried the above code.It gives an error, saying invalid data.