# Node.js - NPM Twitter package - client.get issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, get

I'm having a problem with receiving a working output from a get call to Twitter.

Here's my code and resulting errors:

```
var twitter = require('twitter');

var twit = new twitter({
  consumer_key: '...', (removed keys and secrets)
  consumer_secret: '...',
  access_token_key: '...',
  access_token_secret: '...'
});

twit.get('trends/place', 1, function(error, data, response) {
  if(error) {
    throw error;
  }
  var parseTrend = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(parseTrend);
});
```

This kills my code and throws an "error" of : [object Object]

A second get method:

```
twit.get('search/tweets', {q: 'node.js'}, function(error, tweets, response) {
   var parseTrend = JSON.parse(tweets);
   console.log(parseTrend);
   console.log(tweets.length);
});
```

This results in an error: Status Code: 406

Am I doing something wrong with my syntax or is there a possible problem with the npm packages's get method at this time?

It's worth noting that I am also using a client.stream() method, which is working flawlessly.
So I don't think I'm having any issues with keys or oAuth.

Anyone else having issues?

Comment: I've admittedly only used the twit module. But based on the documentation, this module seems to convert objects' key/val pairs to URL parameters. Did you try passing an object with an `id` property set to `1` as the second argument for your `trends/place` call?

Comment: Just tried: `twit.get('trends/place', {id: 1}, function(error, data, response)` but it returned the Status Code: 406 error like the other get method.

Comment: also tried it with the property as a string" `{id: '1'}` and it resulted in the same.

Comment: Ok, I just tried both of the calls with the node-twitter module, and they worked fine on my end after I removed the JSON.parse statement. I should note that the response the module provides is already in a valid object the JSON format, so a `JSON.parse` call should throw the `Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` error. Are you sure everything is correct with your keys? (If your `client.stream` call is working, I presume it is, but never hurts to double check.)

Comment: I commented out the `JSON.parse` statement, and the console log did put out some new information, but then it threw the event error again with Status: 406. The new log contained the JSON array: `[ { trends:  [ [Object], [Object],...50 times... as_of: '2016-09-19T21:54:20Z',
    created_at: '2016-09-19T21:48:52Z',
    locations: [ [Object] ] } ]` Then the error.

Comment: Oh wait. You said you used the "node-twitter" module. Are you referring to the one created by desmondmorris, or the one created by istrategylabs? They both have the name name on github, but on npm they go by "node-twitter" and "twitter."

Comment: The one by desmondmorris; sorry, used the github name rather than the NPM. That's the correct JSON response. I can't seem to replicate your issue. The 406 error, as per the docs, would suggest something off with your parameters and seems to stem from the streaming API. Could you share your client.stream code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same problem with other Twitter clients? There are [a lot of Twitter modules in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377844/node-js-twitter-client/25006995#25006995) and not all of them work the same way.

After getting strange problems with one of those modules I would suggest to first try some other module and see if the problem persists.