# Can I use a Elastic Search RESTful API without relying on npm of Elastic Search

Tags: node.js, rest, express, elasticsearch, sails.js

We would like to use Elastic Search in our project. The technologies we use are Sails.js and Angular.js. I am trying to integrate Elastic Search into our project. I am not sure whether I can use Elastic Search RESTful API without using npm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use a Elastic Search RESTful API without relying on npm of Elastic Search

(I assume that by "npm of Elastic Search" you mean the Elastic Search module on npm)

**Yes.**

You can use any REST API without using a specific module from npm written for that particular API.

The only question is: **Why?**

But to answer your question, you can use any module that can handle HTTP connections, or you can even use raw TCP sockets for that matter.

So, if your API is RESTful, you can use any of that modules:

- `http`
- `net`
- `request`
- `request-promise`
- a specific module from npm for that service

The first two are core Node modules, other ones are on npm.

Search for HTTP and REST on npm:

- https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=http
- https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=rest

and read the docs of:

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html
- https://nodejs.org/api/net.html

Still it's often useful to use a specific module because it can handle a lot of complicated things for you. For example see how many modules there are to use the Twitter API in Node:

- **[Node.js Twitter Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377844/node-js-twitter-client/25006995#25006995)**

You could use `request`, `http` or even `net` instead of those modules but your code could be significantly more complicated. The same is true for any other RESTful service. You can reinvent the wheel or you can use a well tested solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use Elasticsearch without its (or any other) node module, using any way to talk HTTP (or TCP, as @rsp said).

However, using a *well written* package saves a lot of hassle and you can get your work done much efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a REST/Request client to do this and simply make use of the Query DSL.

That being said, it would make more sense to use elasticsearch-js and structure your queries into a service, helper or adapter.

I personally make use of the latter option and it's worked well for me. Found the existing Sails adapters for ES to be troublesome.