# Twitter api search tweets tweeted by user

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm trying to search tweets tweeted by a specific user, but I can't decipher the documentation.

I read through this page https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search, and this page https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets and I can see that there is no parameter `user` or something similar.

But at the bottom of the first page is:

```
When you want the most popular tweets of a specific user using a hashtag:

You want: popular Tweets from @Cmdr_Hadfield mentioning the hashtag #nasa
Your search URL is: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3ACmdr_Hadfield%20%23nasa&result_type=popular
```

Why isnt that documented on the page anywere? Is `%3A` = `@`? How do I actually make that search?

Edit:

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter - `1.7.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone trying to do the same thing, you just have to decode the characters from the example query

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=from%3ACmdr_Hadfield%20%23nasa&result_type=popular
```

`%3A` would be `:`

`%20` would be

and after that you just write your query:

```
twitterClient.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json', {q: 'from:name param',count: "100"},  function(error, tweets, response){
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(tweets);  
});
```

This should be working. It s working for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are [a lot of Twitter modules in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377844/node-js-twitter-client/25006995#25006995) - it will be much easier to use one of them:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/twitter

See this answer for more options and more details:

- [Node.js Twitter Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377844/node-js-twitter-client/25006995#25006995)

> Why isnt that documented on the page anywere?

I recommend using one of the Node modules for Twitter API. Many of them have great documentation.

> Is %3A = @? How do I actually make that search?

No. `"@"` is `%40`. `%3a` is `":"` (a colon). If you use a Node module to talk to the Twitter API then you will not have to worry about details like that.

Comment: Thank you, but am I not using the right one `"twitter": "^1.7.0"`? The problem was about querying by user if I want to. Am I reading the wrong documentation for the the module?